# Parse complex CSS string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse complex CSS strings, for example a filter:

```
dropShadow(16px, 16px, 16px, rgba(50, 50, 100, 0.8)) invert(75%) blur(10px)
```

This should resolve into 3 parts:

```
dropShadow(16px, 16px, 16px, rgba(50, 50, 100, 0.8)),
invert(75%),
blur(10px)
```

Of course, strings can be quite different:

```
dropShadow(16px, 16px, 16px, #ffcc00),
```

What's the best approach of dealing with this mess that is CSS strings in Javascript? I know Typed Object Model will solve this easily, but the adoption is not quite there yet.

Comment: What are you trying to use it for? Maybe there is a simpler way then regex

Comment: I need to change styles of elements based on input (input being the above mentioned strings).

Comment: Find the indices of the spaces that are not enclosed in parentheses and use `substr` or a similar method to save the substrings. For properties like `filter`, which accept space-separated values, this should do. For comma-separated values, simply splitting the string at the commas will suffice.

Comment: @AngelPolitis some properties take comma separated functions (e.g. `transform: translate(x,y);`) whilst others take space delimited values (e.g. `margin: 0 auto`)

Comment: @KitangaNday both of which are covered in my comment above. Log the indices of the spaces outside any parentheses and use them to create substrings.

Answer (score 1):

As @AngelPolitis stated in the comments:

> Find the indices of the spaces that are not enclosed in parentheses and use substr or a similar method to save the substrings. For properties like filter, which accept space-separated values, this should do. For comma-separated values, simply splitting the string at the commas will suffice.

Here's the code equivalent:

`var parsedResponse = "dropShadow(16px, 16px, 16px, rgba(50, 50, 100, 0.8)) invert(75%) blur(10px)".replace(/\) /g, '),\n');`

Please test it out below and tell me if the returned values are what you were looking for:

```js
// Get the elements in DOM
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var text = input.value;
  text = text.replace(/\) /g, '),\n');
  output.innerText = text;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Place valid css property values here..." value="dropShadow(16px, 16px, 16px, rgba(50, 50, 100, 0.8)) invert(75%) blur(10px)"><button type="button">Output!</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```